# how to update a cookie when option is checked

Tags: jquery

I have a check-list, and I when a user checks the first option I want to get that value. Then, when they checked another option I want to get the second value separately. This is the code I have so far

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').live('click', function() {
var values = [];

$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(index, value) {
    if (this.checked && $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length == 1) {

            values.push($(this).next().html());
        str1 = values[0];
        number1 = str1.replace(/\D/g,"");
        $('#resultsection p').html("<span>" + number1 + " </span> ");

    } else if (this.checked && $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length == 2) {

        values.push($(this).next().html());
            str1 = values[0];
            number1 = str1.replace(/\D/g,"");

            str2 = values[1];
            number2 = str2.replace(/\D/g,"");

            $('#resultsection p').html("<span>" + number1 + number2 + " </span> ");

    } else {

        $('#resultsection p').html("No metrics selected.");
    }
});
```

I have spend a lot of time to change this code to make it work, but so far I failed. Can someone tell me what's wrong with this code?
Thanks

Thanks

Comment: What does the question have to do with updating a cookie?

Answer (score 0):

From what i can tell, in your code you are missing the ending of your `$.each()` function... you are starting `$.each(function(a,b) {`  but then not ending it.

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').live('click', function() {
    var values = [];

  $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(index, value) {
    if (this.checked && $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length == 1) {

            values.push($(this).next().html());
        str1 = values[0];
        number1 = str1.replace(/\D/g,"");
        $('#resultsection p').html("<span>" + number1 + " </span> ");

    } else if (this.checked && $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length == 2) {

        values.push($(this).next().html());
            str1 = values[0];
            number1 = str1.replace(/\D/g,"");

            str2 = values[1];
            number2 = str2.replace(/\D/g,"");

            $('#resultsection p').html("<span>" + number1 + number2 + " </span> ");

    } else {

        $('#resultsection p').html("No metrics selected.");
    }
  }); // you forgot to end your each()
});
```

Comment: thanks for looking at the code.. I missed that end, but still there is a problem with the code.